# ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package?

Tags: python

Command:

python3  main.py  file.dump

I get an error stating that:

File "main.py", line 3, in

```
from .Histogram import Histogram
```

ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

I do not know where i am going wrong. I am in the same directory where the dump file, the Histogram.py file and the main.py file are placed.

For the .py files click on the link below:

https://github.com/riscv-newop/riscv-newop/tree/master/rvnewop

I am clueless.
Where am I going wrong?

Why is the Histogram file not getting imported ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time)

Answer (score 0):

since Histogram.py is in same folder as the main.py, You can simply write

```py
from Histogram import Histogram 
obj = Histogram()
```